# Buy to Detail rate G4

Tags: google-analytics

Do you know if there is a KPI in GA4 that replaces Buy to Detail rate from Universal? I used it for a formula for the Est. Sales Opportunity.
The goal of the KPI is to estimate how much revenue was lost because the user saw an OOS PDP

Checked in G4 but I did not find anything

Thank you so much everybody